Doubt in free end reflection of string wave
When a pulse on string reflects from free end, the resultant pulse is formed in such a way that slope of string at free end is zero.
What is the reasoning behind this statement? How can I prove it?
(Explain at high school level)

This question is similar to: Vibrating string, free end boundary condition. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
